# Nonparametric Regression

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, nonparametric, nonparametric-regression

Suppose I have response `y`, continuous independent variable `x` and binary variable `z`.

```
     x <- rnorm(100)
     z <- rbinom(100,1,0.5)
     y <- rnorm(100)
```

The regression model is `fit <- lm(y~x+I(x^2)+z)`. I want to check if a nonparametric regression can be reasonably well represented by this model. Which nonparametric regression I can carry out for data with both continuous and binary variables?

Answer (score 1):

If some variables are truly binary, then if we adhere to the intuition that "nonparametric" is equivalent (in some sense) to 'distributional-assumption free,' then a linear regression is indeed nonparametric for binary random variables, because all binary rvs have distribution $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ for some $p$, and so for a binary rv $X$, the linear regression $Y = \alpha + \beta Z$ will indeed capture $\beta = p$ (assuming away finite concerns with $p$ close to $0$ or $1$).

Bringing this back to your problem, if we have any binary rv $X$ and cts rv $W$, we can always think of models nonparametrically by specifying $Y = f_1(W)1[X=1] + f_2(W)1[X=0]$, where $f_1,f_2$ are arbitrary functions.

If you're using R, maybe you could start with [general additive models (GAMs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model) using Rs `mgcv` package?

Comment: Yes, but  `gam` function can plot the component smooth functions, like for my particular example, it will give 3 separate plots for three independent variables(x, x^2, and z), whereas I am actually interested to draw a plot where I can fit one curve for the whole nonpaprmetric regression model and another curve in the same plot for the quadratic regression model to compare if they resemble fairly well.